# Some packages are missing in binary when deploy to maven nexus

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I tried to deploy my project jar into central maven Nexus location.Binaries are deployed successfully into nexus`(.sha .md5 sources.jar .jar .pom these files are uploaded)` and i can access them.But when i download and extracted `.jar` file i see some `src` packages were missing.My requirement was that include project `src` folder as a jar(.class files).

Note:After successful build jar will be created in `target` folder and it contains all packages as i expected.But in nexus jar some packages are missing.Please let me know where i went wrong.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.my.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <xtend.version>2.9.0</xtend.version>
        <my-runtime.version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</my-runtime.version>
        <xtendGenDirectory>xtend-gen</xtendGenDirectory>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://.../content/repositories/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <url>https://..../content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>deployment</id>
            <name>Internal Releases</name>
            <url>https://.../content/repositories/releases/</url>(Sample Nexus URL)
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>deployment</id>
            <name>Internal Releases</name>
            <url>https://..../content/repositories/snapshots/</url>(Sampe Nexus URL)
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myproject.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${runtime.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.xtend</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.xtend.lib</artifactId>
            <version>${xtend.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <directory>target</directory>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
        <testOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</testOutputDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${xtendGenDirectory}</source>
                                <source>src</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>add-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src</directory>
                                    <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/classes</targetPath>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>

                                    </excludes>
                                </resource>



                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>add-test-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>test-output</directory>
                                    <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</targetPath>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>

                                    </excludes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scmCommentPrefix>TASK-7:</scmCommentPrefix>
                    <tagNameFormat>releases/v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                    <pushChanges>false</pushChanges>
                    <localCheckout>true</localCheckout>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.xtend</groupId>
                <artifactId>xtend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${xtend.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                            <!-- <goal>xtend-install-debug-info</goal> <goal>xtend-test-install-debug-info</goal> -->
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${xtendGenDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                            <testOutputDirectory>${xtendGenDirectory}</testOutputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <failOnError>false</failOnError>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${project.build.directory}/classes/plan/${TEST_PLAN}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>${xtendGenDirectory}</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: For what purpose are you using these build-helper-maven-plugin executions? Your maven-source-plugin is generating sources.jar and attaching it to build as an output artifact, meaning it's getting uploaded on deploy - is this not sufficient for your use case?

Comment: @Anton Koscejev thanks for your reply.i just put `build-helper-maven-plugin` because i have some resources to attached to the build along with the `src`.eg: `xtendGenDirectory` this is out side from src.do you have any idea why it is getting missed?

Comment: what you're saying is indeed very strange. Whatever jar `source-maven-plugin` generates in `target`, should also be the jar that is uploaded to nexus. How do you upload to nexus? Do you just run `mvn deploy` or do you use release plugin perhaps? Release plugin activates release profile, which includes another sources jar, which might somehow overwrite your sources jar prior to upload. Also, try switching the source plugin goal to `jar-no-fork`, which is the indented goal for use as part of project lifecycle.